# Proper way to change Bootstrap-Vue text field into mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, vuejs3, vuejs-datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap-Vue `<b-form-datepicker>` component and looking for a way to customise the input date field to `mm/dd/yyyy` format. Any proper ways ?

```
<b-input-group class="mb-3">
        <b-form-input
          id="example-input"
          v-model="dateOfBirth"
          type="text"
          placeholder="MM-DD-YYYY"
          locale="en-US"
          autocomplete="off"
        ></b-form-input>
        <b-input-group-append>
          <b-form-datepicker
            v-model="dateOfBirth"
            button-only
            right
            locale="en-US"
            :date-format-options="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit', weekday: 'short' }"
            aria-controls="example-input"
          ></b-form-datepicker>
        </b-input-group-append>
      </b-input-group>
```

Documentation https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-datepicker

Comment: You can use type="date" on the <b-form-input> instead of text

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by simply assign the `selectedFormatted` value from `b-form-datepicker` into the `v-model` value of `b-form-input`.

*Note : Use different v-model value for both `b-input-group` & `b-form-datepicker`*

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: '',
      inputValue: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onContext(ctx) {
      this.inputValue = ctx.selectedFormatted;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <label for="example-input">Choose a date</label>
  <b-input-group class="mb-3">
    <b-form-input
      id="example-input"
      v-model="inputValue"
      type="text"
      placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
      autocomplete="off"
    ></b-form-input>
    <b-input-group-append>
      <b-form-datepicker
        v-model="value"
        button-only
        right
        locale="en-US"
        aria-controls="example-input"
        :date-format-options="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }"
        @context="onContext"
      ></b-form-datepicker>
    </b-input-group-append>
  </b-input-group>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not update the actual datepicker value. 
What I ended up doing is 
<b-form-input
          id="date-input"
          v-model="formatted"
          type="text"
          placeholder="DD.MM.YYYY"
          autocomplete="off"
          @blur="updateDate"
        ></b-form-input>
with the updateValue

    updateDate (ctx) {
      this.content = moment(ctx.target.value, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    },


That seems to do the trick. Remember output value for the datepicker is always 'YYY-MM-DD'

Answer (score 1):

Does setting each component as numeric not achieve the right format?

```html
<b-form-datepicker
  :date-format-options="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }"
  locale="en"
></b-form-datepicker>
```

Gives: `9/16/2020`

Comment: No It won't. It will only changes the Date text above the calandar not the input text field.